# Using variables in an include file

Tags: php

I am able to find a lot of information regarding using variables from an include file, but I am unable to find information on how to access variables from the calling script in the include.

include.php:

```
<?php
echo $myVar;
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$myVar = "Hello";
include 'include.php';
?>
```

This seems simple, can someone please advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Should work just fine.

Comment: What is the exact problem? What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: I feel stupid. This is working. I guess I was just having a problem with scope in my head. Moving from OPP desktop dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you include a file, it will be seen like one big php file. So you can access variables of the main php in the included php and an variables of the included from the main php after the the include.

Answer (score 1):

Php will work from the top down.

When you define a $var in the include file, you will need to include it into the parent // primary script before trying to echo the variables defined inside.

This means if your include.php contains

```
$var = "Test Value";
```

and if your index.php includes this after including the include.

```
<?php 
include('include.php');
echo $var;
?>
```

This will actually look like (to the server 'compiling' the php):

```
<?php 
    //content results of of include();
    $var = "Test Value";
    //index.php 
    echo $var;
    ?>
```

Therefore the code you provided is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way I posted actually works fine. Not sure what my problem was.